# ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

class document {
    protected:
        string name;
        string surname;
        string patronymic;
    public:
        document();
        document(string n,string s,string p){
            name=n;
            surname=s;
            patronymic=p;
        }
        string getName(){
            return name;
        }
        void setName(string n){
        name=n; 
        }
        string getSurname(){
        return surname;
        }
        void setSurname(string s){
        surname=s;  
        }
        string getPatronymic(){
        return patronymic;
        }
        void setPatroymic(string p){
        patronymic=p;   
        }
};

class passport: public document{
    private:
        int number;
        int series;
    public:
        passport(string n_pas, string s_pas, string p_pas,int num,int ser){
            name=n_pas;
            surname=s_pas;
            patronymic=p_pas;
            number=num;
            series=ser;
        }
};
int main(){
    document p0("qqq","qqq","кккк");
    passport p1("Mikhail","Shalaginov","Nikolaevich",1111,1111);
    cout<<p1.getName()<<p1.getSurname();
    return 0;
}
```

Если убрать строки:
passport p1("Mikhail","Shalaginov","Nikolaevich",1111,1111);
    cout<

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 1):

У вас нет тела конструктора по умолчанию класса `document`, который необходим при конструировании `passport`, только и всего.

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!

Comment: Не сомневался :) Если ответ решил проблему - жмите "птичку" слева.